# Preprocessor Definition Setting: Project Properties ->C/C++ -> Preprocessor

Tags: c++, dll, static-libraries, c-preprocessor, static-linking

I have a `Dll`, which I need to `statically Link`.
This `dll` eg. DTE.dll is a `Third party dll`.
My application is facing problem in linking this `dll Statically`.
I wish to Link this `dll ( DteStatic.lib which is newly sent by the third party)`.
There is a setting in the Project Properties `->C/C++ -> Preprocessor: where I need to add DTE_STATIC`.

**My question:** How do I do Static Linking when I have a dte.lib file.

Comment: Look up what DLL means, linking it statically is not possible. However, you don't do that anyway, which kind of puzzles me what your question really is...

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt The OP says he has `DTeStatic.lib`, but the question puzzles me too.

Comment: The dll when I give the path /I"..\thirdparty\vc2005\west\common\dte" , will link the dll Statically and the dll must be present during the compile time. My Issues is when the 3rd party send the new version the dll must be picked with the required version... the DTE_STATIC may fix the problem ..but not sure as the lib Name is  "DteStatic.lib"

Comment: I do understand the dynamic linking, but I am using the include .LIB to link, which is Static Linking

Comment: No you don't: Normally, when using a DLL, you don't load it explicitly but use the dynamic loader which does that on program startup. Still, you need to link with a static library that contains stubs for the functions exported by the DLL. Static linking is when you don't need a DLL at all.

Comment: So if I have a Dte.lib Can you give the steps as to how to statically link. without having the Dte.dll used any where. - @ Ulrich Eckhardt

Answer (score 0):

The `_` won't create any problem. In my project in *Project Properties -> C/C++ -> Preprocessor -> Preprocessor Definitions* I have `_LIB` and `_DEBUG`.

**Edit:**
`DTE_STATIC` is likely some preprocessor definition specific for your library. I don't know anything about `DTE_STATIC`, but as an example let's look how `_DEBUG` definition could work.

You could have some code you want to compile only in debug mode. For example this code can write some debug info on the command line, but it's not a good idea to show this info to your customer in release build. This code could look like this:

```
int x = 4;
x *= -8 << 2;
// ...

#ifdef _DEBUG
printf("DEBUG INFO: %d\n", x);
#endif

// ...
```

If `_DEBUG` is not defined the line between `if` is just omitted. If you set `_DEBUG` in Preprocessor Definition that line is compiled and executed.

Note: Setting preprocessor definition in Visual Studio is equivalent simply writing `#define _DEBUG` on the top of your header files.

Comment: Can you explain me what happens when we add the Macro DTE_STATIC or any other macro for that matter in the Preprocessor Setting.

Comment: Explained in "Edit".

Answer (score 0):

i think you can give the DteStatic.lib while linking , it will do static linking in case visual studio compilers .

Comment: There is  no lib that i have called as "DteStatic.lib"

Comment: DteStatic.lib is not the one send by third party ?